# Access Window Re-sizing

Tags: ms-access, vba

I recently purchased a 34 inch wide screen monitor. I am using the Dell Display Manager to setup different windows enable me to open multiple word documents etc neatly.

When I am using Access I can dock the app window to 1/2 or 1/3 of the screen correctly. However when I open a form (because its a child perhaps?) it doesn't stay within the confines of the parent window or the Dell Display Manager.

So, my idea was to resize any popup forms to the dimensions of the parent access window with the same Left, Top, Width and Height.

However, despite trying a few different techniques I have not been able to achieve this.

Anybody got any ideas?

Thank you!

**Edit:** Thanks Jashin. I have implemented your code but the form is still not showing up as I would have expected. This is the code I have used:

`SetWindowPos hWndChild, hWndParent, mainRECT.wdw_left, mainRECT.wdw_top, mainRECT.wdw_right, mainRECT.wdw_bottom, &H4`

When the form loads the height and left are slightly off, but the form is really thin. I tried getting the width from mainRECT.wdw_right - mainRECT.wdw_left but it had the same result.

**Final Edit:** Got with working with a bit of tweaking of the code provided by @Jashin. Here is the final code:

```
Dim hWndParent As LongPtr  
Dim hWndChild As LongPtr   
Dim mainRECT As RECT      

hWndParent = Application.hWndAccessApp

hWndChild = Me.hwnd

GetWindowRect hWndParent, mainRECT 

SetParent hWndChild, hWndParent   

SetWindowPos hWndChild, 0, mainRECT.wdw_left, mainRECT.wdw_top, mainRECT.wdw_right - mainRECT.wdw_left, mainRECT.wdw_bottom, &H4

Me.SetFocus

DoCmd.MoveSize 0, 0`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not familiar with the Dell Display Manager however, if I understand your problem well, you are looking after some procedure to force positioning of pop-up forms anywhere on screen. As @ThunderFrame suggested you can't do this with Access API but you can do it using Windows API.

Create a module and declare the following functions

```
Public Type RECT
    wdw_left As Long
    wdw_top As Long
    wdw_right As Long
    wdw_bottom As Long
End Type

Public Declare PtrSafe Function SetParent Lib "user32" _
                               (ByVal hWndChild As LongPtr, _
                                ByVal hWndParent As LongPtr) As Long

Public Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowPos Lib "user32" _
                               (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, _
                                ByVal hWndInsertAfter As LongPtr, _
                                ByVal x As Long, _
                                ByVal y As Long, _
                                ByVal cx As Long, _
                                ByVal cy As Long, _
                                ByVal wFlags As Long) As Long

Public Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowRect Lib "user32" _
                               (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, _
                                lpRect As RECT) As Long
```

Note I am using **PtrSafe** and **LongPtr** keywords because I am working on a 64bit system; if you work on a 32bit system you can delete the PtrSafe keywork and substitute Long for LongPtr.

Then in the Form_Open() event of your pop-up form write the following code.

```
Dim hWndParent As LongPtr  ' handle of your parent form (access window or
                           ' any other form you want to set as parent
Dim hWndChild As LongPtr   ' handle of the child pop-up form
Dim mainRECT As RECT       ' coordinates of the parent form

hWndParent = Form_frm_home.hwnd ' or hWndAccessApp to get the handle of
                                ' the main Access Window
hWndChild = Form_frm_child.hwnd

GetWindowRect hWndParent, mainRECT ' this gets the coordinates of the 
                                   ' parent window

SetParent hWndChild, hWndParent   ' set the pop-up form as child of the 
                                  ' parent form

SetWindowPos hWndChild, hWndParent, left, top, width, heigth, &H4
```

The function SetWindowPos allows you to position your pop-up form on the screen anywhere. You can access the coordinates of the parent form from your RECT struct using the following code

```
mainRECT.wdw_left
mainRECT.wdw_top
mainRECT.wdw_right
mainRECT.wdw_bottom
```

The function SetParent allows you to create a child form, so it will stay always in between the boundaries of the parent form and will move with the main form (or Access Window).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this directly using the Access API, but you can use some Windows API functions to achieve the result you're after.
You'll need to perform the following

1. Get the RECT struct of the Access Application window (using the hidden Hwnd property) and the Windows API GetWindowRect function
2. Build a new RECT struct where you'd like your form to be placed, relative to the Application's RECT, and then use the SetWindowPos Windows API function