# Available space for forms in msaccess

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to find a way to get the dimensions of the space available in ms-access to show forms. The yellow part in the image below

[image]

Both height and width would be nice to know but for the moment it is sufficient to get the height to be able to resize forms in the available height.
It depends on the presence of the ribbon and size of windows borders and statusbar. I cannot find any Application properties that show these dimensions.
Is that possible at all?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access Window Re-sizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34653888/access-window-re-sizing)

Comment: That method gives me the outline of the application window but not the yellow part. If we knew the height of the ribbon and the other objects then I could calculate the size but those numbers are also not available.
The best thing so far is to maximise a form and retrieve Me.WindowHeight but it does not look very nice to see a window maximise and restore again

Comment: I tried getting WindowHeight and WindowWidth of hidden form and unfortunately, hidden form does not stay maximized. Why do you need to know this area's dimensions? Why not just DoCmd.Maximize? Or use Tabbed Documents mode?

Comment: @June7, I was wrong. The GetWindowRect API gets the form height with form.hwnd and de application height with Application.hWndAccessApp. The values in the structure are in pixels and when converted to twips ((RECT.wdw_bottom - RECT.wdw_top) * 15) these show the same number as the WindowHeight property of the form. There is no added value to using API's when we can use the WindowHeight property for the same result also the window has to be maximised to get the available space. Why not maximised, sometimes the specifications are dictated :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to create a form .
Lets call him Form1 then
add this to load event and open the form

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

 Docmd.RunCommand acCmdAppMaximize ' to maximize access
 DoCmd.Maximize ' to maximize the form 

 Debug.Print Form_Form1.FormHeader.Height 'if exist
 Debug.Print Form_Form1.PageHeaderSection.Height 'if exist
 Debug.Print Form_Form1.Detail.Height
 Debug.Print Form_Form1.PageFooterSection.Height 'if exist
 Debug.Print Form_Form1.FormFooter.Height ' if exist
'  Total form height is total of the above 

 Debug.Print Form_Form1.Width

 Debug.Print CommandBars("Ribbon").Height ' this is the Ribbon height
 
End Sub
```

Hope that help. ***Important*** all the values are in  <strike>points</strike> (some Strange units of measure from microsoft , google for <strike>points</strike> 2 cm or what ever you like ) Ops... the measure values are in TWIPs as june7 commented.

Comment: I think the measure values are in TWIPs (TWentieth of an Inch Point). 1440 twips = 1 inch; 567 twips = 1cm.

Comment: Thanks for giving it a try, but the numbers don't add up to the height of the access application from the windows API. I did not forget to add CommandBars("Status Bar").Height. @June7, I think TWIPS are pixels*15. Msaccess has no knowledge of the size of the screen in inches/cm when it is connected with an HDMI cable and a generic driver. The GetWindowRect API returns pixels.